# "No such file or directory" while creating new file

Tags: java, android

This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
public void SaveImageToMemory(Bitmap bitmap, String fileName){
    File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ImageEncryptionDemo", fileName+".jpeg");
    try {
        outFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        outFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

        Log.i("app", "Saved image to " + outFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (java.io.IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've no idea why it throws IOException even if:

1. Permissions in Android Manifest are granted
2. `outFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();` should ensure that all necessary parent directories are created
3. Below functions (taken from android docs) return `true`

:

```
/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Permissions in AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest [...]>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Comment: What's the value of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`? What is the result of `mkdirs` (it returns `true` or `false` if the operation succeeded or failed)? Where exactly is the exception thrown and what is the complete stacktrace? Oh, and what is the value of `fileName`?

Comment: @CommonsWare that was actually a problem. I needed to ask for permissions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In 2nd line, you had just got confused. Check this out.

```
    File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/ImageEncryptionDemo/" + fileName+".jpeg");
```

After

```
    /ImageEncryption/
```

You have to use + instead of a comma.